# Integrating MS Teams into Ruby on Rails Web/Mobile app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, microsoft-teams

We are looking into integrating MS teams into our web/Mobile app running on Ruby on Rails. Is there a work around or way to properly implement the Chat and Video Function sof MS teams into the app?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/msteams-client?view=msteams-client-js-latest - there is a JavaScript based SDK. You could use it in order to initialize the client and embed it to the website.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about it, but I think there -might- be some integration between Teams and Azure Media Services for scenarios like this. Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/media-services-overview as a starting point. As an example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/release-notes#new-docs-content-stream-a-microsoft-teams-meeting :

> It's easy to relay your meeting broadcast from Microsoft Teams with a Media Services live event